# How to checkout my Google Safebrowsing lookup code is correct with a valid URL 'hit'?

Tags: google-api, malware, safe-browsing

I am planning on using the [Google Safebrowsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/) to vet incoming URLs in my app. There are a few steps to get through prior to discovering if a URL has malware, etc though:

- Create a combination of possible URLs to match from the base one (with querystring, different levels of paths, hosts, etc).
- SHA256 hash of each of the outcomes.
- query first 4 bytes against a local cache of similar results.
- if a match found on that, query Google's API for the entire hash for authoritative match info.

My issue is I don't have an example match to test my code for the first 3 steps. I might never know there is a bug. Is there an example positive matching URL for this service or is it possible to find a valid url? I don't see malware links in Google search results anymore, so I'm not sure I can get one that way either.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to start with the official test URLs at https://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/.

If you're looking for real phishing sites (which may or may not be on the Safe Browsing list yet), have a look at https://www.phishtank.com/.

Comment: I'm not generating any matches from hashing those URLs. E.G. for `testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/s/unwanted.html` I generate `MmZmNA==` prefix but this finds no match. However when I hit `threatMatches` directly with the URL as a parameter a match is found.